# SSAS Tabular - Only process data where row is new or modified

Tags: sql, ssas, tabular

I have an SSAS cube that imports a view of data form a source system. Each time this processes it imports the full view, however i want to improve performance by only processing the rows that are new or have changed since the last process. Can anyone advise the best way of doing this?

The view has an ID column, along with a created date and a modified date if this helps?

Have not known what to try, even after googling

Answer (score 0):

What is your model processing strategy? Why are you doing a `Process Full`?

There is an option called `Process Add` which loads only new data which has not been provisioned in the cube based on the condition which allows you to segment all modified data which has not been added in the model.

Here's a quick snippet of process add logic:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect("localhostK12")
$db = $server.Databases.Item("AdventureWorks Tabular Model SQL 2012")
$dsv = $db.DataSourceViews.GetByName("Sandbox")
$cube = $db.Cubes.GetByName("Model")
$measureGroup = $cube.MeasureGroups.GetByName("Internet Sales")
$partition = $measureGroup.Partitions.GetByName("Internet Sales")
$queryBinding = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.QueryBinding( $dsv.DataSourceID, "SELECT * FROM FactInternetSales **WHERE OrderDateKey >= 20120215**" )
$partition.Process( "ProcessAdd", $queryBinding )
$server.Disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to filter records which have been modified recently

```
    Select * from table where id, 
     modified_date IN (select id, 
      max(modified_date) from 
    table  group by id) or created_date IS 
        NULL;
```